# How to share a ZFS pool between Debian and FreeBSD?

Tags: debian, freebsd, zfs

I am having a setup of a dual boot PC running FreeBSD 12 and Debian 10. There is a three disk zraid in the system created by FreeBSD which I would like to use as a common storage pool for both operating systems.

In principle I can mount the pool from both OSes, however I get an error because the two host IDs of both installations are different and the pool is not exported during shutdown. I can override it using `zpool import -f`, however it seems not like a very clean solution.

How can I solve this problem? I can think of two possibilities:

1. manually set the host IDs to make the two IDs identical for FreeBSD and Debian (not sure if this is really a good idea, because it is called ID for some reason)
2. put something in the shutdown routine of each OS to make it export the pool automatically. However I would need the corresponding import functionality on startup.

Data consistency and data safety is of big importance, that why I am using ZFS in the first place.

Comment: i think you max mran the guid? in case yes you can also you the native names

Comment: I do not understand the comment entirely. I am talking about the hostid used by ZFS to mark a pool as imported by this instance. This gets erased when the pool is exported. This is not the question I was asking.